CVE-2023-42366 in Alpine 3.19 images on vulnerability scan
I am building an image using base as alpine and vulnerability scans show the following :
                                  Impacted      Fixed
3.19:ssl_client      1.36.1-r15   1.36.1-r25    CVE-2023-42366
3.19:busybox         1.36.1-r15   1.36.1-r25    CVE-2023-42366
3.19:busybox-binsh   1.36.1-r15   1.36.1-r25    CVE-2023-42366 

I tried running update/upgrade apk add , but the resultant image still shows vulnerability.
FROM alpine:3.19

# Install or update the fixed versions of vulnerable packages
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    busybox \
    ssl_client\
    busybox-binsh
# Update the package index and upgrade existing packages
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade --no-cache

# Specify the entry point
CMD ["sh"]

If I add specific version it fails with
RUN apk add --no-cache     busybox=1.36.1-r25     ssl_client=1.36.1-r25     busybox-binsh=1.36.1-r25:
[135](https://github.com/jobs/6781726623#L138/-/jobs/6781726623#L135)0.307 fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.19/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
[136](https://github.com/jobs/6781726623#L136)0.558 ERROR: unable to select packages:
[137](https://github.com/jobs/6781726623#L137)0.560   busybox-1.36.1-r15:
[138](https://github.com/jobs/6781726623#L138)0.560     breaks: world[busybox=1.36.1-r25]
[139](https://github.com/jobs/6781726623#L139)0.560     satisfies: busybox-binsh-1.36.1-r15[busybox=1.36.1-r15]

I might be doing something very silly because it seems so straightforward, but haven't been able to get around it. My requirement is a vulnerability free image so that I can build my downstream images without this vulnerability.
Could you please let me know how can I patch the final image . I had also tried 3.19.1 but even that showed the same CVE.
Thank you.
